# Samsung NP530 laptop cannot enter BIOS setup

Tags: bios

My friend has  a Samsung NP530U3C and he has changed the BIOS to CSM only. Now its stuck on a loop and will not boot up, the options "F2 setup" and "F4 recovery" are there but they do nothing.  I have a bootable USB with Windows 8 that "installs" right up to restart, then....back to the loop or install.

How can I get to the BIOS and change it back to EFI/CSM?

Comment: Changing UEFI to legacy BIOS/CSM shouldn't prevent you from entering the BIOS. Are you saying the key to enter the BIOS is completely ignored now?

Answer (score 1):

Another way to enter BIOS is to hold the shift key while you press restart-> troubleshoot->advanced options->uefi firmware setting->restart. when you get into BIOS, go to advanced, disable fast BIOS mode,then go to boot,disable secure boot,and you will have the OS mode selection where you can choose CSM OS.

Comment: I confirm this. Thx dude.

Answer (score 0):

This case is quite old but few days ago i got Samsung NP310E 5C to repair. It's stuck on reboot loop after power on. I've tried a lot of suggested and found over the internet solutions but without success. I have tried to put Win10, Win8.1, Win 7 installation disks, bootable USB drives... anything.

In my case the solution was simple:

- Power off laptop (holding power button).
- Take off bottom cover,
- Next to HDD area You will find two "jumpers" (soldering points) - they have labels "RTC clear" and "BIOS crisis".
- We need to shortcut "RTC clear" points (I've used paper clip) and holding this connected we power on the laptop,
- After the laptop switch on, we need to wait holding "RTC clear" to CPU fan will increase its speed.
- If the cpu fan switch to "noisy mode", we are taking of shportcut from "RTC clear"
  jumper to "BIOS crisis". We need to do it quite quickly.
- Holding a shortcut on "Bios crisis" spots, we need to wait bios screen will appear on the screen.
- If its not happens - take off shortcut, power off the laptop and try to repeat all steps again. Time between replacing shortcut from "RTC clear" to "Bios crisis" pins are very important. The quality of shortcuts are also important.

Good luck.