# Samsung laptop can't access the bios

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, boot, ssd, bios

my superior officer using samsung laptop (NT530U3C) and he wants change hdd to ssd. 
First, that model has hdd and Windows8. And he wants to change to Windows7.
I think it's start of nightmare.

When I remove hdd and change to ssd, laptop said about 'secure boot'. So I change again ssd to hdd and change the options about secure boot.
(I changed these options through Control panel - UEFI settings in Windows 8)
-Secure boot: Disable
-OS mode: CSM mode
After that I change hdd to ssd again. And I install Windows 7. I think it goes well. But after install laptop can't boot. And then I try to fix, I change ssd to hdd. But it also didn't work. So I think use F4 key to access  Samsung recover tools and it looks working(hdd). But after recover it also can't booting.

When I power on the laptop, it shows "all boot options are tried press f4 key to recover bios".
So I try to access bios, I type F2 to using but I can't. F10 or Tab, Esc other keys also. 
Finally I think it's matter of motherboard. So I disassemble laptop and get rid of motherboard battery and laptop battery. But it also didn't work.

Some video said using window 8 booting image USB or dvd, can access UEFI options. But it's also can't.

Plz help me. It drives me crazy. I want to escape.

Comment: What is the full model number?  I believe US versions are NP530U3C-Axxxxx.   External keyboard can't hurt to test.  With no hard drives can you get into the BIOS?

Comment: I think...it's NT530U3C-a7h.. And I will try to without hdd.

Comment: Does this similar question assist with an alternate method to ender the BIOS? http://superuser.com/questions/620163/samsung-np530-laptop-cannot-enter-bios-setup?rq=1

Comment: Okay, i will try shift key when it boot. thx.. I'm sad laptop isn't here. I hav to go to office to get laptop..

Answer (score 1):

I'm the writer.
I got samsung service.
They said my motherboard was borken.(And they said that model's motherboard is 500$.)Anyway...they try re-programming IC on motherboard then my laptop can boot.
So if you have same problem with me
don't waste time. Just get samsung service.